# How to know the commonality degree of a given phrase?

Tags: phrases

We encounter a lot of phrases/expressions on a daily basis:

- What's up
- It's up to you
- It's your call

How do we know which one is more common?

One might hear a phrase in a movie, and enjoy that seen and based on some cognitive bias believe it's a common phrase. He perceives it as common, because of his joy. In fact, one phrase might be rare and we percieve it as common and use it a lot in our idiolect. Do we have objective measures to find out which phrase is more common than the other?

Comment: This question would be much better served on the meta site for this SE.  It's not a bad question, but it's off topic for the main site.  There's likely no way to determine the commonality in spoken word.  But, Ngrams on google are an easy way to determine prevalence in literature.

Answer (score 2):

You could do a comparative quantitative search of the phrases on Google's ngram, but this would apply only to literature.

https://books.google.com/ngrams